# Access denied to SQL database (wamp)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I was installing WHMCS on my wamp localhost but it required a password for the database which is blank by default, so I went in to phpmyadmin and added a password. Whenever I try to connect the database now I just get this error. `Could not connect to database server: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

[Screenshot of the installation page and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekVr2.jpg)

Comment: When you added the password in phpMyAdmin, did you definitely go to the User accounts page, then edit the one for user test with host localhost? Which user were you logged in as? Are you able to log in to phpMyAdmin as user 'test' now with your new password (or with no password)? Usually what people who have your problem have done is set a password for a different user (probably user `test` with host `%`).

Comment: Yes I did, and I changed the right account (root) and host.